# Recursive php mysql query/function for tree of categories

Tags: php, mysql, recursion, recursive-query

I have an oscommerce set up and have decided to add a "most popular" product in each category. I need to query all child categories so that I can then query for the most popular product in the list and display it.

HOWEVER.

I have this function and I just can't seem to get the array of category id's out of it. Is this issue to do with scope??

```
 $children_ids = array(); 

function fetch_children($parent) {     

 $result = tep_db_query('SELECT `categories_id` FROM categories WHERE parent_id = "'.(int)$parent.'"'); 

   while($row = tep_db_fetch_array($result)) {


        $children_ids[] = (int)$row['categories_id'];


        fetch_children($row['categories_id']);
   }   
}
```

At this point I am not trying to access the array of data using the `$children_ids` variable however this doesn't seem to contain anything!? I've also tried `array_push();`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to modify a global variable from inside a function. You may declare that variable global from inside the function body (but I would strongly recommend against it) or have the function return the array of children_ids, which would be something like this (not tested):

```
function fetch_children($parent) {

  $result = tep_db_query('SELECT categories_id FROM categories WHERE parent_id = "'.(int)$parent.'"');
  $list = array();
  while($row = tep_db_fetch_array($result)) {

    $list[] = (int)$row['categories_id'];


    $list = array_merge($list, fetch_children($row['categories_id']));
  }
  return $list;
}

$children_ids = fetch_children($root_node_id);
```

Comment: Thanks Carlos! This looks like it will make sense, I thought it was to do something with the scope, it makes sense, I will try this on when i return back to the office and will let you know!

Comment: Hi Carlos, This I thought would work in theory, but it appears to only run the function once or return only the first set o results from the first query. Any ideas?

Comment: hm seems I forgot to bind the result of `array_merge` to a variable. Try `$list = array_merge($list, fetch_children($row['categories_id']);`